# How to reload UITableViewCell Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have image in my `UITableViewCell` and after changing the constraints of cell w.r.t image height I want to reload the cell.

I tried this approach but this function is taking little time to execute and hence, app is getting hang for a while.

```
[cell reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Can you tell me the other approac to simply **reload the cell** instead of table ?

Comment: it may be achieved if you set content hugging and content compression priority according to the behaviour. i.e. set content hugging to 249 and content compression to 751.

Comment: can't you change the row height after all its content being populated?

Comment: indexPaths takes array. You can use literals like this: reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath1]

Comment: @RicardoAlves I am changing the cell height after populating the data itslef but in that case, cell is taking the height which I have kept in mainstoryboard i.e. the standard cell height then it is considering the height which I kept in the code even it is before populating the data. As sson as , I am manual refreshing the cell by scrolling up or down, the changes are showing up.

Comment: @GeneCode Can you please tell me what is indexpath1 ?

Comment: indexPath1 is NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]; (if u want to reload cell at row1 in section0)

Comment: No @GeneCode ... I am getting this error by using... as I have only sections but no rows.. 
      -[NSIndexPath firstIndex]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc000000000200016

Comment: try calling `heightForRowAtIndexPath` at the end of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @RicardoAlves I tried it... But it doesn't helped as my cell height is dynamic with respect to Image size and Image size is available in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: check answer bellow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**objective c**

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

> To reload row 2 of section 1 and row 3 of section 2 for example,
>   you'll have to do this :

```
NSIndexPath* indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1];
NSIndexPath* indexPath2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:2];
// Add them in an index path array
NSArray* indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath1, indexPath2, nil];
// Launch reload for the two index path
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

> OR YOU CAN ALSO DO LIKE THAT

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

//*************************************************************************

**SWIFT**

```
override func reloadRows(at indexPaths: [Any], with animation: UITableViewRowAnimation) {
}
```

> To reload row 2 of section 1 and row 3 of section 2 for example,
>   you'll have to do this :

```
var indexPath1 = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 1)
var indexPath2 = IndexPath(row: 3, section: 2)
// Add them in an index path array
var indexArray: [Any] = [indexPath1, indexPath2]
/    / Launch reload for the two index path
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: indexArray, with: .fade)
```

> OR YOU CAN ALSO DO LIKE THAT

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPathOfYourCell], with: [])
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Shall I use indexpath or Indexpath with row/section ?

Comment: table view : section

Comment: No, it is not helping... BY this method app is crashing by saying... "Array is exceeding the range by 3"

Comment: I had used this code: row is 0 as I am using only section in my design.
            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
            NSIndexPath* indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:indexPath.section];
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath1,  nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            [self.tableView endUpdates];

Can you tell me where is it wrong for my reference ?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the image size before loading the image completely and after that change the cell height to what you pretend

```
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

NSMutableString *imageURL = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myimageurl.com/image.png"];

CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[NSURLURLWithString:imageURL], NULL);
NSDictionary* imageHeader = (__bridge NSDictionary*) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
NSLog(@"Image header %@",imageHeader);
NSLog(@"PixelHeight %@",[imageHeader objectForKey:@"PixelHeight"]);
```

with this you can get the image size, adjust the UIImageView and get the height for it to be dynamic

For you to be able to do this asynchronous you can use [YYWebImage](http://github.com/ibireme/YYWebImage)

Comment: I have tried getting the image size but with this my application got hang for few seconds.

Comment: Thank you for replying. It helped little bit. 
Along with this, I used [cell setNeedsLayout];  [cell layoutIfNeeded]; 
Finally , It worked :)